# Sharing data stored in angularjs

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

I'm trying to shared data between controller.
I'm calling data, then stored in AngularJS Factory variable.
My goal when stored the data was to make it accessible to any controller. But in application, every time i called the stored data from each controller, seems like i got a new instance of my factory instead of my factory that already contain the data.

Do you think i'm doing the wrong way when using factory or there was something i've been missed ?

Here it is

Factory Code:

```
var Credentials = ['abc'];
function load() {
    var service = HeaderService.get("api/CredentialsAPI/get");
    service.then(function (response) {
        if (response.status == 200)
            Credentials = response.data;
    });
    alert("inside:" + Credentials.length);
}
load();
return {

    SubmitCredentials : function (obj) {
        angular.forEach(obj, function (value) {
            Credentials.push(value);
        });
    },

    GetCredentials : function (name) {
        var datax = {};
        alert(Credentials.length)
        angular.forEach(Credentials, function (value) {
            if (value.Name == name) {
                datax = value;
            }
        });
        return datax;
    }
}
```

Home Controller:

```
loadHome();
function loadHome() {

    $scope.Credentials = CredentialsService.GetCredentials("Task");
}
```

AssignTask

```
$scope.showSubmitView = false;


//----------------------------------function--------------------------------------

$scope.Credentials[] = CredentialsService.GetCredentials("Task");
```

Comment: Post some code, please.

Comment: This SO question should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21919962/share-data-between-angularjs-controllers

Comment: There are multiple answers, blogs and tutorials on how to share data between controllers. If you show your code I'm sure someone will help you however.

Comment: @KKKKKKKK Done.. Any idea ?

Comment: @tasseKATT i'd like to save my data first in order to avoid redundant

Comment: @IanOctoBear You're referencing a new array every time under `$scope.Credentials = []` in both controllers.  That's why your data keeps wiping.  You need to reference the service, then have the service take care of the `push()`.

Comment: @KKKKKKKK how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're referencing a new array every time.  That's why you're getting new data.  You should be referencing the service instead, and have the service take care of the `push()` and get for you.

Factories and Services are singletons... Meaning they're only instantiated once.  The pattern to share data is below:

**Factory**

```
app.factory('CredentialService',["$http", function($http) {
    var credentials = [];

    var submitCredentials = function(obj) {
        angular.forEach(obj, function(value) {
            credentials.push(value);
        });
    }

    var getCredentials = function(name) {
        var datax = {};

        if(credentials.length === 0)
            return datax;

        angular.forEach(credentials, function(value) {
            if(value.Name === name) {
                datax = value;
                break; //i think you meant to break; over here
            }
        });

        return datax;
    }

    //return the service;
    return {
        getCredentials: getCredentials,
        submitCredentials: submitCredentials
    };
}]);
```

**Controller**

```
app.controller("Ctrl1", ["$scope", "CredentialService", function($scope, CredentialService) {   
    var credObj = CredentialService.getCredentials('blahblahblah');

    var someNewCredObj = 'blahhhh';
    CredentialService.submitCredentials(someNewCredObj);
}]);
```

Comment: So are you suggesting that i called my API service from my factory instead of my controller ? Because i need my API service to fill factory data

Comment: Yes, you should encapsulate your API calls inside a service.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, i'm still had a problem. i can't get my data unless in my controller i use $http service to access the factory in order to get data. if not using it, i got nothing. Any Idea ?

Comment: i'm already try encapsulate api calls like you suggested. or am i doing the wrong way ? @KKKKKKK